# Cloning win 7 32 bit from HD to SSD Macrium reports incompatible sector size

Tags: windows-7, ssd, cloning

Created a drive image of Win 7 Prof 32 bit on an HP 6930P laptop from the internal Seagate 160Gb HD on to a USB 3 TB Toshiba HD with Macrium (5.something,latest free download) and verified. 
Bought new Crucial M500 240 Gb SSD. Attached SSD to USB port of laptop via SATA/USB 2.0 adapter. 
Mounted SSD and quick formatted from Win 7 using MBR option. 
SSD works normally.
However as soon as I tried to restore the Win 7 image from the 3TB USB drive to the SSD via USB/SATA, (using same laptop) Macrium refused saying sector size was incompatible. 
I checked sector size of SSD via win 7 system properties, and it reports as 4096 Kb as expected. 
I thought the firmware on an SSD was supposed to emulate the sector size on hard drives, and if it doesn't how come they work anyway? If it does why does Macrium complain? (I tried Easus as well, and that starts to clone and then asks to which drive it should write, but doesn't seem to see the SSD at all).

Comment: Is this any help? The USB adaptor may be the problem. http://kb.macrium.com/KnowledgebaseArticle50193.aspx